# sql query to sum of amount column

Tags: php, mysql

my table has data like below...

Now there are 18 rows in my below table...but receipt no are same.

**but i need to display sum of amount of unique receipt no only.**

**plz help me to make sql query.**

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM `receipt_entry` group by receipt_no,amount


receipt_no              amount
    10                    100
    10                    100
    10                    100
    10                    100
    10                    100
    10                    100

    11                    100
    11                    100
    11                    100
    11                    100
    11                    100
    11                    100

    12                    100
    12                    100
    12                    100
    12                    100
    12                    100
    12                    100

  SUM of Amount        = 300
```

FOR Above ex - i need to sum amount like below =100+100+100= 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this query:

```
SELECT SUM (A.AmountTotal) FROM  (
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount) AS AmountTotal, receipt_no 
    FROM receipt_entry
    GROUP BY receipt_no ) A
```

This block returns the result of:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amount) AS AmountTotal, receipt_no 
FROM receipt_entry
GROUP BY receipt_no

AmountTotal     receipt_no
-----------     ----------
100             10
100             11
100             12
```

Again add sum of the block, gives the result.

> UPDATE:

```
SELECT SUM(`AmountTotal`) FROM  (
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT `amount`) AS AmountTotal, `receipt_no` 
    FROM `receipt_entry`
    GROUP BY `receipt_no`) AS T1;
```

Can you check this query.

Working example of this scenario: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76277/14)

Comment: but this return error #1630 - FUNCTION circulation_scheme_prepaid.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct` clause before `sum` data.

Do like this:

```
$query = "SELECT sum(amount) AS total_amount, receipt_no 
          FROM receipt_entry 
          GROUP BY receipt_no"
```

> You can get more detail on DISTINCT from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)

Let me know for more help !!

Comment: no this wont work  bcoz you have put distinct on amount ...but this is also possible that amount is same for all but receipt no was different....

Comment: pls try my edited answer, hope it will work for new requirement. !! Is it working ???

Comment: no sir you simply sum amount ...i need if there are 6 rows with same receipt no then count it only 1 row...for ex - in above table receipt no 10 present in 6 rows then count this only 1 row...